# Jest: how to test mock argument has property (ignoring rest of argument class)?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am wanting to test that a class method is called with a particular argument. That argument is an instance of a class and I am interested in whether one of its properties matches an expected object.

```
export default class MyEventSqsHandler {
    private readonly sqs: SQS.SQSClient;

    constructor(sqsClient: SQS.SQSClient) {
        this.sqs = sqsClient;
    }

    async putEventOntoSqs(body: string | null): Promise<void> {

        if (body) {
            await this.sqs.send(new SendMessageCommand({
                MessageBody: 'some body',
                QueueUrl: 'someUrl',

            }));
        }
    }

...
}
```

The object in the constructor of `SendMessageCommand` sets a property called `input` and it is this input that I wish to check.

My test:

```
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-sqs');

test('putEventOntoSqs_callsSqsSend_bodyIsNotNull', async () => {

    const mockSqsClient = new SQS.SQSClient({});
    mockSqsClient.send = jest.fn();

    const eventSqsHandler = new MyEventSqsHandler(mockSqsClient);

    await eventSqsHandler.putPageLoadEvent('some body here');

    expect(mockSqsClient.send).toBeCalledWith(..something goes here...);

});
```

I want to test that the AWS SQS client is called with a `SendMessageCommand` where that `SendMessageCommand` has an input property of some value of interest. Is there a way of accessing the `input` property of the received command and checking that against an expected object? There may be fields in the `SendMessageCommand` that my mock receive which I am not interested in checking.

For reference, the return type of the `send` command I am mocking is a `Promise<void>`.

Comment: Is `SendMessageCommand` something you own? If not, having assertions based on what its constructor does with the values you're passing in seems dicey.

Comment: No, it's an AWS-provided class.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not testing it this way, then. It's one thing to test that you interact with the library in the expected way (in this case what you call new SendMessageCommand with, then that you call the send method with the result), that's already a bit too coupled, but when you're testing what the library does internally with those arguments you're coupling beyond even their public API. You shouldn't have to care what the input prop is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use [`expect.objectContaining()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) to test the structure of objects.

```
expect(mockSqsClient.send).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    input: expect.anything(),
}));

expect(mockSqsClient.send).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    input: 'some explicit value',
}));
```

**Jest**

Some other examples of testing values/structure:

```
class MyType(){
    myType = true;
}


expect({
    key1: new MyType(),
    key2: new MyType(),
}).toEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
        key1: expect.any(MyType),
        key2: expect.objectContaining({
            myType: expect.any(Boolean),
        }),
    })
);


expect({
    key3: null,
}).toEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
        // `expect.anything()` matches any value that's not null or undefined, 
        // so this will fail
        key3: expect.anything(),
    })
);
```

**Jasmine**

This originally comes from the Jasmine test API that Jest was based on, so there are additional examples in their docs:

- https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E
- https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/jasmine.html#.objectContaining

(but note that it uses the `jasmine` object instead of expect)

```
expect({
    key1: new MyType(),
    key2: new MyType(),
}).toEqual(
    jasmine.objectContaining({
        key1: jasmine.any(MyType),
    })
);
```